# Retrieve the list of users in the "Only allow access to specific users" under DEPLOYMENTS

Tags: google-app-maker

In Google App maker, I am trying to create a Form Dropdown widget populated with all users (emails or names) that I have put in the "only allow access to specific users" section under DEPLOYMENTS. Basically, a list of all users who are allowed to use the app.

> Does anyone know if this is possible (either through Scripts or bindings) to access this information from within a "Page"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do this. Nevertheless, [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#specify_who_can_run_an_app_deployment) states:

> Enter the email addresses of specific users (Google Accounts), groups (Google Groups), or both.

That means that instead of adding user by user, you can simply add a google group and then users that require access can be added to the group and as well can be removed if they no longer require it.

Then, you would simply get the list of the users who have access by getting the list of members in the group. For that, you can use the [getUsers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getUsers()) method of the [Groups Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/) to retrieve a list of direct members in the group.

You'll have to run that via server script and here is a snippet of how it should be:

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "examplegroup@mydomain.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers().map(function(member){
      return member.getEmail();
  });
  return users;
}
```